# PHP - session_id does not point the the right session_name

Tags: php, session, cookies

We are using a server that has several services on it. So to make sure the php sessions are not mixed, we want to use a different cookie for each service. We created a function called `sec_session_start` where we define the cookie (`mySession`) for this service. We then made a second function called `start_my_session` to connect to the service cookie.

Each time we try to use `start_my_session`, it gets the info inside PHPSESSID instead of mySession. How can I fix that.

The following function is called only at one place (when the user logs into the system).

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $secure = false;
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate the safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);

    session_name('mySession');
    session_start();        // Start the PHP session.

    echo session_id();      // USE AT THE MOMENT FOR DEBUGGING ONLY
}
```

The session id returned by the last instruction is the id corresponding to the mySession cookie. (I checked in the server /tmp folder and inside Chrome's resources debugger.)

The following function is called inside everyother secure page once the user is logged in.

```
function start_my_session() {
    echo session_name('mySession').'<br>';   // DEBUG : display PHPSESSID
    echo session_name().'<br>';              // DEBUG : display mySession
    session_start();        // Start the mySession

    echo session_id();                // DEBUG : display the PHPSESSID session id
}
```

As mention in comment, the session_id is still pointing to the PHPSESSID instead of the mySession.

Any advice on what we are doing wrong and how we could fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not sound very logical and you'll think I'm nuts but:

Before you switch session names with `session_name(...)` (and yes, that means it's also before the session is started!)... run a `session_write_close();`

Comment: Tried it and works. But why? Does it closes the PHP default session and make room for the new session I try to make?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. As far as I can see, there is no session to close in the first place. Seems like a bug in PHP's logic somewhere.

Comment: sounds good. Thank you for you time. I've been hitting my head on this for 20 hours (in several days).